# Editar rtf em tempo de execução

Tags: delphi, rtf

Abaixo segue um código de uma linha de um arquivo RTF no qual preciso editar em tempo de execução.

```
\clvertalc\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx7800\clvertalc\clbrdrl\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrt\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrw10\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrw10\brdrs \cellx9926\pard\intbl\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\sb20\sa60\cf1\kerning1  %Riscos%\cell\pard\intbl\nowidctlpar\hyphpar0\qc (S/N)\cell\row\trowd\trgaph70\trleft-1134\trqc\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl70\trpaddr70\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3\trowd\trgaph70\trleft-1134\trrh397\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10 \trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10 \trpaddl70\trpaddr70\trpaddfl3\trpaddfr3
```

Aqui, seguem dois exemplos (Um de como está e um de como deve ficar)

Como está:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como deve ficar:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dúvida é: Qual tag devo usar para que tenha este efeito? Já pesquisei muito na internet, mas o que encontrei apenas são tags onde apenas o Microsoft Office Word tem suporte, o que necessito é que o WordPad (Também Microsoft) consiga suportar.

Se puderem enviar documentos em pdf para estudos 'offline' eu agradeceria demais. links de estudos também são bem vindos.

Comment: Teoricamente seria so adicionar `\b Risco: Animais domes... \b0`

Comment: Exatamente, após verificar exaustivamente por aqui cheguei nessa solução que você postou. apanhei, mas como nunca tinha, mexido no código fonte de arquivo rtf....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As propriedades de controle de determinadas palavras de controle têm apenas dois estados. Quando essa palavra de controle não possui nenhum parâmetro ou possui um parâmetro diferente de zero, presume-se que a palavra de controle ativa a propriedade. Quando essa palavra de controle tem um parâmetro 0, presume-se que a palavra de controle desativa a propriedade.

Temos a propriedade `\b` que ativa o inicio do negrito. E para desativar aṕos a sequencia pre determinada de texto, usamos o `\b0`.

Assim para resolver o seu problema, pode usar dessa forma:
`\b Risco: Animais domes... \b0`

<sup>Fonte: http://www.biblioscape.com/rtf15_spec.htm</sup>